# Every_Minute Trigger in AWS Lambda limited to 4 processes

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, triggers

I have a dozen+ lambda functions that need to be fired every minute, but the Lambda trigger refuses to create another after 4 Every_Minute triggers are already active.

Is there a way around this?  Am I violating a best practice?  Is this just an AWS problem?  I have an outstanding support request with them, but StackOverflow always seems to answer concerns better than them (even about AWS) in my experience.

Comment: Is there a specific error message it returns when it "refuses to create..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/cloudwatch_limits_cwe.html

Specifically, the "Targets: 5/rule" found at the bottom of the table.  Screenshot here in case the link above moves:
[image]